# How to make an Interactive discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so, Im making a discord bot and I want to add a feature to it (sort of an interactive one where help request can be done via bot dm and support team can answer through the bot).

When bot receives DM, with ".helpme" or ".gethelp", it checks in my discord server/guild if there is already any channel named like that guy's discord ID.
If there isn't any named like it, then, it would take his ID, and create channel, for example: "#328792756715651072" (This is to prevent spam)

After that, I made it so, whenever that channel is made, that it mentions every helper in that channel, and deletes that message after a second.

And at the end, I made it really simple, so whenever a message is sent in that channel (example: #328792756715651072), that bot sends message to that guy, as well as name and discord tag of that person (And I also made a role next to it, so he can know what rank is he) - (Example: Senior Helper | God#9936 >> Hello).

Also, after the guy sends something to bot in DM, bot would check if channel with his ID "#328792756715651072" exist in that guild. If it doesn't exist, it would say he doesn't have help request open. If it exist, it would just send that message to that channel, with his name next to it. (Example: God#9936 >> Hello)

And at the end, I made command for helpers, which was .quithelp, which was just a simple command that deleted the channel after 10 seconds.

So it worked without saving any variables, or storing anything in any data.

I would like to get help on the codes for this, like an example code would be very helpful!
Thank you <3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Hello sir, not really...I am not asking someone to write a code for me...I just got this idea, but I can work on it if I get an example of this one. All I need is an example code (a small one would do).

Answer (score 0):

**A quick guide**
First, you will need to import the discord module.
**Install:**

```
npm i discord.js
```

**import:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Now, you need to actually get your bot online.
You will start by defining your client.

```js
const client = Discord.Client();
```

Then logging your client in.

```js
client.login('yourTokenHere'); //make sure this line goes at the bottom of your code to prevent future errors.
```

You can get a token by [clicking here](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
**When the bot logs in, log it.**(optional)

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Now logged in as ' + client.user.username + '.')
}
```

**Adding a message event listener**
Now, when a message is sent you want your bot to read the message.
You will do this by adding an event listener:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    //Code goes here
}
```

**Reading all messages that was sent**
Inside of your event listener you will want to see the message content.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    var prefix = '.' //Your prefix
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        //The message is a command
    }
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        //The message was a DM.
    }
    message.channel.send('Message read'); //sending a message in the same channel as the message was sent.
}
```

Comment: you have a missing `'` in `message.channel.type === 'dm`